# Externally adding another layer to convolution output

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a network in which the data comes from a stack of images and a vector of numbers.
I begin with two "branches": The images go through several convolutions and produce an output of shape `(50, 50, 64)`. In the other branch I import the number and go:

```py
x = Input(shape = (13)) # data vector is of length 13
x = Dense(50*50)(x)
x = Reshape((50,50))(x)
```

I now have 2 outputs from the branches - one is of shape `(50, 50, 64)` and the other of shape `(50, 50, 1)`. How can I "stick" them together to get a collective `(50, 50, 65)` which I'd then `Deconv2D`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the keras `Concatenate()` layer as in follows:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers

# create some dummy tensors with numpy and the keras backend
arr1 = K.constant(np.zeros((50, 50, 1)))
arr2 = K.constant(np.zeros((50, 50, 64)))

# and this is how you call the concatenate layer
combined = layers.Concatenate()([arr1, arr2])

# it should print this: 
# Tensor("concatenate_1/concat:0", shape=(50, 50, 65), dtype=float32)
print(combined)
```

Comment: I just figured out the the third dimension `1` has to be specified for the `Concatenate` to work. Can you perhaps elaborate on why? Surely `Reshape`ing from 1 to 2 dimensions makes for an obvious 3rd dimension (= 1).

Comment: Usually you have to specify along which axis to concatenate since there could be different ways to concatenate if the tensors have symmetric shapes. For example you have two tensors of shape `(50, 50, 50)`, these two tensors could be concatenated in 3 different ways such that you end up with `(100,50,50)`, `50,100,50` and `50,50,100` depending on which axis you concatenate along. I hope this makes sense. I'm not sure what you mean with the second part of your comment though, if you could elaborate on the reshaping.

Comment: If my output from a `Dense` layer is a tensor of length 2500, and I `Reshape((50,50))(x)`, the resulting shape would be `(None, 50, 50)`, but with what you explained I see why a third dimension has to be specified in `Reshape((50,50,1))(x)` to get the shape `(None, 50, 50, 1)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy function : `np.c_`

try:

```
>>> x.shape
(50, 50, 64)
>>> y.shape
(50, 50, 1)
>>> z = np.c_[x,y]
>>> z.shape
(50, 50, 65)
```